# How to format in Python like 1'123'456,00

Tags: python, format

How can I format `",.2f"` to sort of `"'.2f"` or what I should to do to change comma separator to `'` in formating with format()

```
format (123456789, ',.2f') => 1,234,567.89
```

to

```
format (123456789, '???.2f') => 1'234'567.89
```

Comment: `format (123456789, ',.2f')`.replace(',', "'")`

Answer (score 1):

What you can do as a workaround is do the normal format method and use replace() to replace the comma (,) with (').

```
format (123456789, ',.2f').replace(',', "'") => 123'456'789.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
s = f"{123456789 / 100:,}".replace(",", "'")
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
1'234'567.89
```

Comment: Thanks, bro! f-strings will useful to me next time

Answer (score 0):

To get `1'234'567.89`, use:

```
format(123456789*0.01, ',.2f').replace(',',"'")
```

Output: `"1'234'567.89"` as intended.